# SP 2013 : bind timer execute to Execute method

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I prepared in Visual studio 2012 WSP farm solution deployed to SP 2013. WSP package contains feature with Timer job. After **install**, **deployment**, **activating features** via Powershell I can see my Timer definition in central admin. But when timer fires (hourly) my custom code (Execute method in my class) is not called. Timer service restarted. 
In CA job history everything looks good; but my code is not invoked by timer process. Why ?

My solution contains also event receiver on `ItemUpdated` event, and I had to force PS to bind event listener (snippet) :

```
$list.EventReceivers.Add($type, $assembly, $class)
```

Must I do something similar in this case ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend attaching the debugger in VS to OWStimer process and step through the code. Here is a link to the process (it refers 2010 but still valid for 2013) http://sharepoint-kings.blogspot.com/2013/02/debugging-custom-sharepoint-timer-jobs.html

Comment: Thank you, but this is not development environment. No debugging, no install VS shell etc.... Other way: If debugger will stop in my Execute  method, everything is ok  ,no ? Because in that moment I am in my class and I am logging execution of my business.